# How to set color or highlight PositiveButton and NegativeButton in alert dialog box and customized

Tags: java, android, xml

I am searching for set color in the alert dialog box positive button. But I didn't get any solution, so please suggest me any one good solution for the alert dialog box.

My code is here

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Delete ");
        alertDialogBuilder
        .setMessage("Are you sure, you want to delete ")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {                    

                datab=mdb.getWritableDatabase();
                datab.execSQL("DELETE FROM demo WHERE student_id='"+getid+"'");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully deleted", 10).show();
                Intent i=new Intent(StudentInfo.this,MainActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(i);                               }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});
```

I want to set RED color for Yes Button in the alert dialog box.

Comment: make custom alert box.

Comment: How can i customized alert box please suggested any link or please past demo code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simple one! Create a dialog method something like this anywhere in your Java class.

```
public void openDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context); // context, this etc.
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_demo);
    dialog.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Now create Layout XML dialog_demo.xml and create your UI/Design. Here is a sample one I created for demo purpose.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/dialog_text"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/dialog_info">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="@color/dialog_cancel_bgcolor"
            android:text="Cancel"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_ok"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="@color/dialog_ok_bgcolor"
            android:text="Agree"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now you can call openDialog() from anywhere you like :) Here is the screenshot of above code
[image]
Note that text and color are used from strings.xml and colors.xml. You can define your own. Hope this is helpful. Thanks!

**other wise you can use this code it works for me**

```
    public void createDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit from app");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You exit from app",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    Button nbutton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
    nbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    Button pbutton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    pbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
}
```

Comment: This code really working well, thank you for suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Buttons via:

```
alertdialog.show();
//possible Buttons:  BUTTON_NEGATIVE, BUTTON_NEUTRAL, BUTTON_NEUTRAL
Button myPositiveButton = alertdialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
//pseudo code for now:
myPositiveButton.setOnClickListener(...);
myPositiveButton.setBackgroundColor(...);
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion.